# Filtering a python dictionary using another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I am currently trying to find a more pythonic way of filtering a dictionary using another dictionary. Currently I have the following code:

```
def filter_respondents(data_dict, tolerance):
    NaN_dict = diagnostic_tools.get_NaN_ratio(data_dict)
    final_dict = {}            
    for respondent in data_dict:
        if NaN_dict[respondent]<=tolerance:
            final_dict[respondent] = data_dict[respondent]    
return final_dict
```

The code does what I want it to do but I'm looking for a better way of doing it. Basically I have 2 dictionaries. data_dict is a dictionary with the key-value pairs id:response and NaN_dict has the key-value pairs id:value. If value is below tolerance, I want the key-value pair with the same ID in data_dict to be included in final_dict.

I came up with something like:

```
final_dict = {k:v for k,v in data_dict if NaN_dict[k]<=tolerance}
```

Which I know is wrong, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost right. Seems that the only thing missing is to call `.items()` for getting key-value pairs:

```
{k: v for k, v in data_dict.items() if NaN_dict[k] <= tolerance}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was perfect.