# Filter dictionary for values which are not in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

The two dictionaries `mydict1` and `mydict2` are given. Key-value-pairs in `mydict2` should be removed if the values are already contained in `mydict1`, regardless of the key and regardless of the order of the values.

The code below delivers the correct output `mydict2 = {'key6': [2,1,4], 'key4': [2]}`. However, it will be used as part of a larger code. Is there is a better, i.e. more phytonic, way to write it in order to make it more compact and effective without the need of functions?

```py
mydict1 = {'key1':[1],'key2':[1,2],'key3':[1,2,3]}
mydict2 = {'key4':[2],'key5':[2,1],'key6':[2,1,4]}
mydict3 = {}

for md2 in mydict2:
    isindict = False
    for md1 in mydict1:
        isindict = isindict|(sorted(mydict1[md1])==sorted(mydict2[md2]))
    if not isindict:
        mydict3[md2] = mydict2[md2]
mydict2 = mydict3
```

The solutions for [removing items from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), [comparison of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911273/is-there-a-better-way-to-compare-dictionary-values) and [conditional filtering of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358933/filtering-a-python-dictionary-using-another-dictionary) are not transferable in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and dict comprehension to sort all the values of `mydict2` then check if the sorted value of `mydict1` is in there:

```
mydict1 = {'key1':[1],'key2':[1,2],'key3':[1,2,3]}
mydict2 = {'key4':[2],'key5':[2,1],'key6':[2,1,4]}

vals = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in mydict1.values()]
mydict2 = {k:v for (k,v) in mydict2.items() if tuple(sorted(v)) not in vals}

print(mydict2)
```

Or, in one line:

```
mydict1 = {'key1':[1],'key2':[1,2],'key3':[1,2,3]}
mydict2 = {'key4':[2],'key5':[2,1],'key6':[2,1,4]}

mydict2 = {k:v for (k,v) in mydict2.items() 
        if tuple(sorted(v)) not in [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in mydict1.values()]}

print(mydict2)
```

Comment: You are creating the same list of tuples for every key/value pair in `mydict1`

Comment: @PeterWood If you want to memoize the list of tuples, then use the version with the extra line `vals=...`

Comment: @PeterWood I guess I'm not sure what you're getting at because my answer only creates a single list of tuples in the first code example, not a list for each key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension :

```py
mydict1 = {'key1':[1],'key2':[1,2],'key3':[1,2,3]}
mydict2 = {'key4':[2],'key5':[2,1],'key6':[2,1,4]}

results = {key : value for (key,value) in mydict2.items() 
           if set(value) not in [ set(val) for val in mydict1.values()]}
print(results)
```

> {'key4': [2], 'key6': [2, 1, 4]}

### Edit1

Doesn't work wiht duplicate like this :

```py
mydict1 = {'key1':[1],'key2':[1,2],'key3':[1,2,3], 'key4' : [1, 1, 2]}
mydict2 = {'key4':[2],'key5':[2,1],'key6':[2,1,4], 'key7' : [2, 2, 1]}
```

### Edit 2

Following @Ruzihm awsers and @Peter Wood comments :

```py
mydict3 = {k:v for (k,v) in mydict1.items() 
        if tuple(sorted(v)) not in set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in mydict2.values())}
```

This awser the OP question and avoid creating multiple time the same tuple of value as mentioned by @Peter Wood.

Comment: What if the order of elements in `value` are different?

Comment: Fails with `[1, 1, 2]`, `[2, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work:

```
mydict1 = {'key1':[1],'key2':[1,2],'key3':[1,2,3]}
mydict2 = {'key3':[2],'key5':[2,1],'key6':[2,1,4]}

def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y) 
    return z

result = merge_two_dicts(mydict1, mydict2)
print(result)
```